# 401 error When sending incorrect credentials using JWT?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

So I am working with JWT, When I insert a valid data ( username and password ) I get a response with 200 in status, but I insert an incorrect data I get 401 error with a message saying Bad credentials, Which is not good obviously, because I will always get a red beautiful error in the browser console.

I am working with Symfony 4 api platform, and here is files needed to do such task,

security.yaml :

```
security:
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt
  providers:
    #in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    database:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: username
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    api:
      pattern: ^/api
      stateless: true
      anonymous: true
      json_login:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And the User entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "force_eager"=false,
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
 *     },)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface {

    /* 

    Just Variables and getters and setters here 

    */

    public function getRoles(){
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }

    public function getSalt(){

    }


    public function eraseCredentials(){

    }


}
?>
```

So I don't know what is causing the problem, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What behavior do you expect to see?

Comment: Is that normal ? getting an error of 401 in the console ? I don't know Actually, I was waiting for a 200 response with a message of 'Not Ok" for example because I get a message of 'OK" when authenticating correctly ? M I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case errors is normal. In REST, you use status codes to tell an frontend application what something went wrong. Example '200 response with a message of 'Not Ok"' bad idea, because status code 200 mean 'Everything okay' but in message you tell what went error. 
Often errors status codes 4** uses for this purpos, for example 400 - Bad request or 422 - you send not valid data to backend/

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the clarification.